# DataGridView and Combobox Column?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

when DataGridView has a combobox column, how can I get the text it displays as oppose to the value it represents? When I do `DGV.Item("cbo",i).Value` I get the value but it won't take `DGV.Item("cbo",i).Text`. I trying `Ctype(DGV.Item("cbo",i),ComboBox).Text` and this does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

DGV.item("cbo",i).DisplayMember

Answer (score 0):

Umm are you talking about Win Forms?
If so, `Value` is the property you want, and is what is to be displayed on the screen and held behind the scenes.
If you want something different not shown to the user, I've often used the property `Tag` for that.

Comment: Yes, winform. Value gives the value/ID not what is displayed

Answer (score 0):

I found this, and the answers didn't work for me. In case someone else finds this, here is what I did.

```
dgv.rows(i).Cells(cboname.index).EditedFormattedValue
```

Hope if someone finds this through Google it will help them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dgvcmbcell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DgvItemsUnits.Item("UNIT_SER", 0)
    Dim SelectedText As String = dgvcmbcell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString()
```